# How to get document one time and using it every where

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I using firebase admin and use nodejs get data by phone number from firebase. When i get success , i want get only document one time and use it every time. It possible ?

Picture :

[image]

First i get document by phone look like.
Example:

```
const phone = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('phone_number', '==', phone).get()
```

After that , i want using document phone every time in my code look like :

```
await handleLogic(phone)
```

Then

```
 async function handleLogic(phone) {
   //inside here i need call await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('phone_number', '==', somePhone).get() or re use phone in parameter ?  
 phone.ref.collection("subcollection").get()
        .then(() => {
            let data = {
                
                created_at: timeNowFirebase(),
            };

            phone.ref.collection(subcollection).doc(someId)
                .set(data);
  }
```

I have question : Inside function handleLogic(phone), i need re call **admin.firestore().collection('users').where('phone_number', '==', phone).get()** or only use parameter **phone** and used `phone.ref.collection(subcollection).doc(someId).set(data);` . It will set subcollection into document my phone correct ?

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your documents and explains from where are you trying to copy data and to where?

Comment: how about you use cache

Comment: @Dharmaraj I just updated picture. I just question when i used  phone.ref.collection("subcollection").get() i  need re call await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('phone_number', '==', phone).get() or don't call it. phone.ref.collection("subcollection").get() will automatic get correct my document  by phone number ?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra why i need use cache this case

Comment: Where are you running the `phone` query at first place? If you could share the code in the order it runs than it might help us understand what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @Dharmaraj

My code order look like :

First : 
const phone = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('phone_number', '==', phone).get()
Second :
await handleLogic(phone)
...
function handle logic phone

I just question if i order it, i only use document phone one time and use it on function handle logic don't need re call get document by phone.

Comment: It might be best if you edit and update your question with the code as is.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I just edit my question.

Comment: Essentially you are asking is querying the document by phone number only once outside of `handleLogic` and preserving the in memory works instead of querying everytime `handleLogic` works?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yes. Correctly. It just query one time outside of handleLogic  and working correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can store the document ID (or even the `DocumentReference` as you are currently) in memory/cache instead of querying the document with phone number every time. The doc ID never changes and this seems to be a good way to prevent additional requests to the database.

```
// storing in memory for example
const phoneToUserId = {};

async function handleLogic(phone) {
  if (!phoneToUserId[phone]) {
    // run a query to get userID from phone number
    const user = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('phone_number', '==', somePhone).get()
    phoneToUserId[phone] = user.docs[0].id
  } 

  // get a reference to sub-collection
  const subCol = admin.firestore().collection(`users/${phoneToUserId[phone]}/subcollection`)
  // query data
}
```

However do note that you'll have to update that object whenever user updates their phone number or delete their document.

Comment: It mean my code in my post correct ? And when i use  phone.ref.collection("subcollection").get()
        .then
It work correct

Comment: @BaoTrungTran yes that works too. I mean value of `phone.ref` will never change. But again if you are storing data of multiple users then you'll have to use map. Otherwhise phone.ref will have same value always. It's not clear how are you storing data from first query..